# htaccess redirect all variants to https

Tags: redirect, server, .htaccess

Using CWP, I have setup a webserver powered by Apache + NginX + Varnish.

I want the following domains samples to open https variants, i.e. https://example.com

```
example.com

www.example.com

http://www.example.com

http://example.com

https://www.example.com

https://example.com
```

Hosted websites are developed using CodeIgniter, so index.php also needs to be bypassed.

My current .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

But it's not working. The following variants makes websites inaccessible on all variants

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

and tried some other variants also even after referring to articles here at Stack Overflow, none is working for me.

> RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
> says too many redirects

There is no effect of any other variant. http and https works fine in them, but no redirection to https is achieved.

Comment: Every `http` request to `https`. Is this the question?

Comment: And what does "But its not working" actually mean? What happens, you need to tell us, we cannot somehow guess that. A wrong redirection? An error message? Which? Nothing? What does your http server's error log file reveal?

Comment: @arkascha RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L] says too many redirects. There is no effect of any other variant. http, https all works but there is no redirection in other variants.

Comment: @vivek_23 All the variants which are expected to redirect are mentioned in the beginning of the post

Comment: @ITSagar Can you better show a 1-1 mapping indentation? It's not very clear to me as to which is going to which one and which not.

Comment: @vivek_23 example.com, www.example.com, http : // www.example.com, http : // example.com, https : // www.example.com, https : // example.com

  All should go to: https : // example.com